# Can you do Nested Copy loops in ARM Templates?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to dynamically generate path mappings to route incoming traffic to the correct backend pool of an App Gateway.

For example we have 20 tenants, and we allow 5 tenants per backend pool, meaning we will generate 4 backend pools.

I need to create the path mappings dynamically such that Backend Pool One serves tenants1-5, Backend Pool Two serves tenants6-10, etc.

The desired array that I'd like to generate is:

```
[
    [ "tenant1", "tenant2", "tenant3", "tenant4", "tenant5"],
    ["tenant6", "tenant7", "tenant8", "tenant9", "tenant10"],
    ["tenant11", "tenant12", "tenant13", "tenant14", "tenant15"],
    ["tenant16", "tenant17", "tenant18", "tenant19", "tenant20"]
]
```

With this array formed, I can then create the backend pools and join the sub array strings to form the path mappings I need.

Here is a quick prototype of one of the attempts made...

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
  },
  "variables": {
    "totalTenants": 20,
    "tenantsPerBackendPool": 5,
    "copy": [
      {
        "name": "outerCopy",
        "count": "[div(variables('totalTenants'), variables('tenantsPerBackendPool'))]",
        "input": {
          "copy": {
            "count": "[variables('totalTenants')]",
            "name": "innerCopy",
            "input": "[if(equals(div(copyIndex('innerCopy'), 5), copyIndex('outerCopy')), concat('/tenant', copyIndex('innerCopy'), '/*'), json('null'))]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "resources": [
    // Multiple backend pools will be created here, and use the path mappings to route correctly
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "pathMappings": {
      "type": "array",
      "value": "[variables('outerCopy')]"
    }
  }
}
```

However I'm getting the following exception:
`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: 16:01:18 - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template language expression evaluation failed: 'The template language function 'copyIndex' has an invalid argument. The provided copy name 'innerCopy' doesn't exist in the resource.`

Comment: I've hard coded my expected output for now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do the nesting approach in the OP, but I think you can produce the array of arrays that you want:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {
        "totalTenants": 20,
        "tenantsPerBackendPool": 5,
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "firstPass",
                "count": "[variables('totalTenants')]",
                "input": "[concat('/tenant', copyIndex('firstPass', 1), '/*')]"
            },
            {
                "name": "finalpass",
                "count": "[div(variables('totalTenants'), variables('tenantsPerBackendPool'))]",
                "input": "[take(skip(variables('firstPass'), mul(variables('tenantsPerBackendPool'), copyIndex('finalPass'))), variables('tenantsPerBackendPool'))]"
            }
        ]
    },
    "resources": [ ],
    "outputs": {
        "firstPass": {
            "type": "array",
            "value": "[variables('firstPass')]"
        },
        "finalPass": {
            "type": "array",
            "value": "[variables('finalpass')]"
        }
    }
}
```

That help?

Comment: Skip/take in ARM Templates, I've seen it all now! Thank you Mr Moore.

Comment: Here is a resource for the above technique: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-variables