# Assigning Static Ip to nic(copy loop) in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to change dynamic private ip allocated VM to Static IP via ARM template.

It works for a single vm. But facing issue for multiple VM's deployment. I am trying nested deployment.

The error I am facing is: The template reference "nic-"somevmname"-01" is
not valid: could not find template resource or resource copy with this name.

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the nested resource

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
 "parameters": {

"VnetResourceGroup": {
  "type": "string"
},
"VnetName": {
  "type": "string"
},
"SubnetName": {
  "type": "string"
},

"adminusername": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "Admin username for VM"
  }

},
"adminpassword": {
  "type": "string"
},
"vm-name": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": ""
  }
},
"virtualMachineCount": {
  "type": "int",

  "metadata": {
    "description": "Number of Virtual machines to be deployed"
  }
},
"vmSize": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "description"
  }
},
"vm-image-name": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "description"
  }
},
"vm-image-rg": {
  "type": "string",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "description"
  }
},

"dataDisksize": {
  "type": "int"
},
"datadisks-count": {
  "type": "int"

},

"osDiskType": {
  "type": "string"

},
"osDiskSize": {
  "type": "int",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "description"
  }
},
"maxAvailabilityzones": {
  "type": "int",
  "metadata": {
    "description": "description"
  }
}
  },

"variables": {


"ImageReferenceId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('vm-image-rg'), '/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/', parameters('vm-image-name'))]",
"vnetId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('VnetResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('VnetName'))]",
"subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
},
 "resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
  "name": "[concat('nic-',parameters('vm-name'),'-0', copyIndex(1))]",
  "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "copy": {
    "name": "nicLoop",
    "count": "[parameters('virtualMachineCount')]"
  },
  "properties": {
    "enableAcceleratedNetworking": true,
    "ipConfigurations": [
      {
        "name": "ipconfig1",
        "properties": {
          "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
          "subnet": {
            "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},

{
  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('vm-name'),'-0', copyIndex(1))]",
  "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "zones": [
    "[string(add(mod(copyIndex(0), parameters('maxAvailabilityzones')), 1))]"
  ],
  "copy": {
    "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
    "count": "[parameters('virtualMachineCount')]"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "nicLoop"


  ],
  "properties": {
    "hardwareProfile": {
      "vmSize": "[parameters('vmSize')]"
    },
    "osProfile": {
      "computerName": "[concat(parameters('vm-name'),'-0', copyIndex(1))]",
      "adminusername": "[parameters('adminusername')]",
      "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminpassword')]"


    },


    "storageProfile": {
      "copy": [
        {
          "name": "dataDisks",
          "count": "[parameters('datadisks-count')]",
          "input": {
            "lun": "[copyIndex('dataDisks')]",
            "name": "[concat('dataDisk',copyIndex('dataDisks',1),'-',parameters('vm-name'),'-0',copyIndex(1))]",
            "createOption": "Empty",
            "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('dataDisksize')]"
          }
        }
      ],

      "imageReference": { "id": "[variables('ImageReferenceId')]" },
      "osDisk": {
        "name": "[concat('osdisk-',parameters('vm-name'),'-0', copyIndex(1))]",
        "createOption": "FromImage",
        "caching": "ReadWrite",
        "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('osDiskSize')]",
        "managedDisk": {
          "storageAccountType": "[parameters('osDiskType')]"
        }
      }
    },
    "networkProfile": {
      "networkInterfaces": [
        {
          "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat('nic-',parameters('vm-name'),'-0', copyIndex(1)))]"
        }
      ]
    },
    "diagnosticsProfile": {
      "bootDiagnostics": {
        "enabled": true
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
  "name": "StaticIP",
  "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
  "dependsOn": [
    "nicLoop",
    "virtualMachineLoop"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "expressionEvaluationOptions": {
      "scope": "inner"
    },
    "parameters": {

      "SubnetRef": {
        "value": "[variables('SubnetRef')]"
      },

      "virtualMachineCount": {
        "value": "[parameters('virtualMachineCount')]"
      },
      "vm-name": {
        "value": "[parameters('vm-name')]"
      }

    },
    "template": {

      "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
      "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
      "parameters": {

        "subnetRef": {
          "type": "string"
        },


        "virtualMachineCount": {
          "type": "int",

          "metadata": {
            "description": "Number of Virtual machines to be deployed"
          }
        },
        "vm-name": {
          "type": "string",
          "metadata": {
            "description": "description"
          }
        }
      },

      "variables": {

      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
          "name": "[concat('assignstaticip',copyIndex(1))]",
          "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "copy": {
            "name": "nicStaticIpLoop",
            "count": "[parameters('virtualMachineCount')]"
          },
          "properties": {
            "ipConfigurations": [
              {
                "name": "ipconfig1",
                "properties": {
                  "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
                  "privateIPAddress": "[reference(concat('nic-',parameters('vm-name'),'-0', copyIndex('nicStaticIpLoop',1))).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]",
                  "subnet": {
                    "id": "[parameters('subnetRef')]"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
],
 "outputs": {

"vm-ipaddress": {
  "type": "array",
  "copy": {
    "count": "[parameters('virtualMachineCount')]",
    "input": "[reference(concat('nic-',parameters('vm-name'),'-0', copyIndex(1))).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]"
  }
},
"vm-name": {
  "type": "array",
  "copy": {
    "count": "[parameters('virtualMachineCount')]",
    "input": "[concat(parameters('vm-name'),'-0', copyIndex(1))]"
  }
}
  }
 }
```

Comment: Finally I found a working example from here:

https://cloudiseasy.com/2020/04/10/arm-template-to-create-nic-with-static-ip-without-sending-the-ip-in-parameter/

Thank you Praveen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @*Anonymouus*, for sharing the update . And bring the question for `how to change dynamic private ip allocated VM to Static IP via ARM template`, It will be really helpful for the SO community for similar issue who encounter the same so that they can find & fix their problem by posting it as an answer .

As stated in the given [**`Blog`**](https://cloudiseasy.com/2020/04/10/arm-template-to-create-nic-with-static-ip-without-sending-the-ip-in-parameter/) which is Author by @***Praveen***.

> *To change the dynamic IP to static IP through ARM TEMPLATE we can use the below example of template*,
>
> ***ARM TEMPLATE:-***
>
> ```
>  {
>       "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
>       "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
>       "name": "[concat('StaticIp', copyIndex())]",
>       "dependsOn": [
>         "nicLoop"
>       ],
>       "copy": {
>         "name": "ipLoop",
>         "count": "[parameters('ServerInstanceCount')]"
>       },
>       "properties": {
>         "mode": "Incremental",
>         "template": {
>           "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
>           "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
>           "resources": [
>             {
>               "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
>               "name": "[concat(parameters('ServerNamePrefix'),padLeft(copyIndex(),3,'0'),'-NIC')]",
>               "apiVersion": "2018-03-01",
>               "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
>               "tags": "[parameters('tagValues')]",
>               "properties": {
>                 "ipConfigurations": [
>                   {
>                     "name": "ipconfig1",
>                     "properties": {
>                       "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
>                       "privateIPAddress": "[reference(concat(parameters('ServerNamePrefix'),padLeft(copyIndex(),3,'0'),'-NIC')).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]",
>                       "subnet": {
>                         "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
>                       }
>                     }
>                   }
>                 ],
>                 "enableAcceleratedNetworking": true
>               }
>             }
>           ]
>         }
>       }
>     }
> ```

*For more information please refer the below links:-*

- **SO THREAD**| [***Static ip addresses on Azure***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66678399/terraform-static-ip-addresses-on-azure/66702294#66702294) &  [***Nested Copy loop using ARM Template***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71941728/nested-copy-loop-arm-template).